# Create Action<T> where T is baseclass of Method parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to do something like a CommandBus, where a method should be called when a command is processed. I store these in a Dictonary

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<BaseCommand>> _commandHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Action<BaseCommand>>();
```

So when a Command of Type StartCommand is processed I find the Action to execute from this Dictonary.

The Method that the StartCommand should call looks like this.

```
public void StartCommand(StartCommand command)
```

The **StartCommand** inherits the **BaseCommand**

I am trying to populate the Dictonary with this code.

```
    var commands = new List<Type>();

    //-- Get all commands that is defined in assembly
    var tmpAssembly = typeof(CommandBus).Assembly;
    commands.AddRange(tmpAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(BaseCommand)));

    commands.ForEach(c =>
    {
        var methodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 1
                                                                        && m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.ParameterType == c));
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            var action = (Action<BaseCommand>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<BaseCommand>), instance, methodInfo);
            if (!_commandHandlers.TryAdd(c, action))
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("An CommandHandler is already registered for the command: '{0}'. Only one CommandHandler can be registered for a command", c.Name));
        }
    });
```

When I run this code I get the following exception: *Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.*

And that is ofcourse correct since my mehtod doesn't take a **BaseCommand** as parameter but a **StartCommand**

But is there some way that I can create the Action? I have looked at som examples with Expression but I didn't manage to figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use Interface instead of a base class. This way it will work, I think.

Comment: You have the variance in the wrong direction. We have `delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);`, so `Action<>` is contravariant, not covariant. The method you find by reflection, will accept only special "commands" (`StartCommand`), not general ones (`BaseCommand`). If what you were trying to do was possible, I could invoke `action(evilCommandNotStartCommand);`. That would send a reference to a wrong object into the method.

Comment: Juach: I tried that it didn't help.

Comment: Jeppe: I see the problem but i don't help me. I could of course go for the name of the method and have BaseCommand as parameter of the method, and cast it to StartCommadn in the method. But I think that is more error prone that what I am trying to achive here.

Comment: Hum...

I think maybe other "patterns" are better for what you are trying to accomplish. Who will provide the classes (like the class StartCommand) and who will provide the routines, like the routine void StartCommand(StartCommand command) ?

Comment: I will. Or other member of our team. It's closed code not something that is public, it's only for our team and this project. Wanted a generic method to connect the Command and the  method that should be called in a generic way so I don't have to write the code for connecting the command to the method for each command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem a little confusing, for a couple of reasons:

1. It's not clear to me why an *instance* method of type e.g. `StartCommand` should itself need a different instance of `StartCommand` to be passed to it.
2. It's not clear to me why the parameter type of this de facto interface method has to be the same as the declaring type.

I would think that the more usual way to approach this sort of thing would be to have the types implement an interface, or at the very least use the same method signature, i.e. with the base class type as the parameter type instead of the implementing class's type.

That said, if you really want to do it the way you describe, you were on the right track with the `Expression` class. You can create an expression that will explicitly cast to the type you need to invoke the member, so that the delegate instance itself can receive the base type instead.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create an Action&lt;T> delegate instance which will call the
/// given method, using the given instance, casting the argument
/// of type T to the actual argument type of the method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type for the delegate's parameter</typeparam>
/// <param name="b">The instance of the object for the method call</param>
/// <param name="miCommand">The method to call</param>
/// <returns>A new Action&lt;T></returns>
private static Action<T> CreateAction<T>(B b, MethodInfo miCommand)
{
    // Create the parameter object for the expression, and get
    // the type needed for it
    ParameterExpression tParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Type parameterType = miCommand.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

    // Create an expression to cast the parameter to the correct type
    // for the call
    Expression castToType = Expression.Convert(tParam, parameterType, null);

    // Create the delegate itself: compile a lambda expression where
    // the lambda calls the method miCommand using the instance b and
    // passing the result of the cast expression as the argument.
    return (Action<T>)Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.Constant(b, b.GetType()),
                miCommand, castToType),
            tbParam).Compile();
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
var action = CreateAction<BaseCommand>(instance, methodInfo);

if (!_commandHandlers.TryAdd(c, action))
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("An CommandHandler is already registered for the command: '{0}'. Only one CommandHandler can be registered for a command", c.Name));
```

Replace the type name `B` with whatever you actual controller type is. Unfortunately, your code example doesn't show the declaration of `instance`, so I can't use a real type name here.

Naturally, you'll have to be careful to make sure you are passing instances of the correct type when the delegate is actually invoked! The above is just like doing a cast, and will throw an exception just like casting would, if the type is not actually castable to the parameter type for the method.

Comment: Hi! The instance is not the startcommand. The instance is a Controller class, that has a method: void StartCommand(StartCommand  command). So I go through the controller class to try to find the method that has a parameter that matche my command. And the I store the Type of the command with the Action to that method in a Dictonary. So when a command is received I look in the dictonary for what Method to execute. I will look at you Code and see if I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: In your example, your controller class is the same type as the parameter for the method, so that's how my example is structured. But you can change `t.GetType()` in the `Expression.Convert()` factory method call to be whatever type you need to pass to the method. I will update the example so that it's more general and should still work in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input info, I would like to suggest a different approach.

Instead of trying to look into the method argument to find the type to bound to the command handler, it would be better to split different command handlers on their own classes. This way, you can avoid the complexity of having to deal with delegates for different types, not to mention that your code would be more readable, easy to test, etc.

The idea I present you is to store classes instead of methods, with a standard method for executing the command.

So, first we create an user attribute to use with our command handlers. This way you just add the attribute to the class, with the type of command you want to bind to it.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class CommandTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected Type fCommandType;

    public CommandTypeAttribute(Type commandType)
    {
        fCommandType = commandType;
    }

    public Type CommandType
    {
        get { return fCommandType; }
        set { fCommandType = value; }
    }
}
```

Than we create two interfaces, one for the command and one for the command handler. The command interface is empty now, but you can use it with to expose common data/methods for the command handler.

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    void Execute(ICommand data);
}

public interface ICommand
{
    // common data for commands
}
```

We create two commands for our tests:

```
public class StartCommand : ICommand
{
    //Start command data
}

public class OtherCommand : ICommand
{
    //Other command data
}
```

Than, we create our command handler (you can have now many you want, this is for demonstration). We will create only one, so to be able to test what happens when we want to run a command that do not have a command handler bound to it. We tell which command is attached to this command handler through the attribute and we implement the ICommandHandler interface.

```
[CommandTypeAttribute(typeof(StartCommand))]
public class StartCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public StartCommandHandler()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(ICommand data)
    {
        StartCommand scData = data as StartCommand;
        if (scData == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid command for CommandHandler 'StartCommandHandler'. Expecting 'StartCommand' but received {0}", data == null ? "null" : data.GetType().Name));

        //start command execution
    }
}
```

And here we create a "commands manager" class. It has two methods, one to fill the commands dictionary and the other to execute a command.

```
public class CommandManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ICommandHandler> fCommands = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ICommandHandler>();

    public void FillCommandsList(Assembly[] commandDataAssemblies, Assembly[] commandAssemblies)
    {
        var data = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in commandDataAssemblies)
            data.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand))));

        var commands = new List<Type>();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in commandAssemblies)
            commands.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommandHandler))));

        foreach (Type dataType in data)
        {
            foreach (Type commandType in commands)
            {
                Type commandDataType = commandType.GetCustomAttribute<CommandTypeAttribute>().CommandType;
                if (commandDataType == dataType)
                {
                    if (!fCommands.ContainsKey(dataType))
                    {
                        fCommands[dataType] = (ICommandHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(commandType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("A command handler is already registered for the command: '{0}'. Only one command handler can be registered for a command", dataType.Name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        if (command == null)
            return;

        Type commandType = command.GetType();

        if (!fCommands.ContainsKey(commandType))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Command '{0}' not found", commandType.Name));

        ICommandHandler commandHandler = fCommands[commandType];
        commandHandler.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

Here I put a class so you can test this system.

```
public class TestSystem
{
    public void Run()
    {
        CommandManager cm = new CommandManager();
        cm.FillCommandsList(new Assembly[] { this.GetType().Assembly }, new Assembly[] { this.GetType().Assembly });

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing command StartCommand");
            cm.ExecuteCommand(new StartCommand());
            Console.WriteLine("Command executed with success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception raised.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing command null");
            cm.ExecuteCommand(null);
            Console.WriteLine("Command executed with success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception raised.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing command OtherCommand");
            cm.ExecuteCommand(new OtherCommand());
            Console.WriteLine("Command executed with success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception raised.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to add commands already in the list of commands");
            cm.FillCommandsList(new Assembly[] { this.GetType().Assembly }, new Assembly[] { this.GetType().Assembly });
            Console.WriteLine("Command add with success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception raised.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, you do not need to create an instance of each command handler to store in the list. You can also store the command handler type and instantiate in the same way only when it must be executed.

EDIT:
I found that the GetCustomAttribute is only available beggining in the DotNet 4.5.
If you are using an older version, it's possible to use a different code on this part:

```
object[] atts = commandType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandTypeAttribute), true);
if (atts.Count() <= 0)
    continue;

Type commandDataType = (atts[0] as CommandTypeAttribute).CommandType;
```

Comment: Hi Jauch. It's really nice pattern and I would have giving you a vote up for it if I been allowed to :), but and there is always a but. I didn't tell the whole story there is more than a controller, there is also other classes that should execute codes on the same command. So a command is sent to the controller that should do something based on that command, and one thing could be to send the command to another class that should do something else. So based on the class that gets the command different codes should be executed, the command is the same but the code is different.

Comment: Mayby I could use your approce with some tweaks in my solution, I guess I should rethink the solution abit... Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @user3766842, The approach I suggest is still valid. You have only to add a new layer before calling the ExecuteCommand, on your "controller" class, that would check if the command should be executed by itself (with ExecuteCommand) or passed to another class. :)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler isn't letting you do it because the operation conceptually isn't safe.  You have a method that requires its parameter to be a `StartCommand`.  It can't accept an `EndCommand`, a `SomeOtherCommand`, etc.  But by assigning the method to an `Action<BaseCommand>` you're specifically saying that it can accept any of those types of commands as its parameter.  What would you expect to happen if this code could run?

```
public static void Start(StartCommand command) { }
```

---

```
Action<BaseCommand> action = Start;
action(new EndCommand());
```

Now, if you happen to be able to ensure that this won't ever happen, and that if you assign your method to an `Action<BaseCommand>` you will ensure that this situation never comes up, then you can get around this through a cast.  By casting the `BaseCommand` to a `StartCommand` in the body of the delegate the method does technically accept a `BaseCommand`, it'll just fail at runtime if anything but a `StartCommand` is passed.

You should only do this though if you have complete control over the `Action<BaseCommand>` delegates that you'r dealing with, and are able to ensure that they correct parameter types are always passed.  If you're exposing them to external code that may not be aware of these constraints, then this is likely not a viable solution.

In the code I have above this implementation would be done most simply through a lambda with a cast:

```
Action<BaseCommand> action = command => Start((StartCommand)command);
action(new EndCommand());
```

But since you're using reflection, you can just use a lambda that invokes the `methodInfo` that you have, and no cast is needed.

```
var methodInfo = ...;
if (methodInfo != null)
{
    Action<BaseCommand> action = command => methodInfo.Invoke(null, command);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi. I don't want to use methodInfo.Invoke because of the performance. It's okay that it take some time to initilize the dictonary since that is only done once. But the executing of the methods for the command needs to have as good performance as possible..